# pyautogui cant move inside hidden icons

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

so i wanna open a driver for my mouse because long story short, i want to change my mouse led from green to red when something happens. But when i run a test code, everything works just fine until Pyautogui clicks on the hidden icons tab then click on an icon. Pyautogui cant do anything from there. It doesn't freezes but it can not move.

so here is my code:

```
    import pyautogui
    import time
    from time import sleep
    
    
    x = 1
    
    while x == 1:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1696, 1058)
        pyautogui.click()
        sleep(0.7)
        print(11)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1760, 900)
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.click(1200, 1070)
        pyautogui.click()
        sleep(0.7)
        print(12)
        pyautogui.move(200, -300, 5)
        pyautogui.click()
        sleep(0.7)
        print(13)
        pyautogui.moveTo(870, 437)
        pyautogui.click()
        sleep(0.7)
        print(14)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        sleep(0.7)
        print(15)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1220, 827)
        pyautogui.click()
        sleep(0.7)
        print(16)
```

(btw sorry for my bad  english)

Comment: If you're using your mouse while this script is running, your mouse inputs and keypresses will conflict with the inputs being generated by pyautogui. You'll effectively be fighting with the script for control of the devices resulting in neither of you getting what you want.

Comment: We're not capable of diagnosing what's going on since we have no idea what is on your screen at every step of your script. This is particularly difficult since you are expecting this script to change what is on your screen, every time you call `click()`, `move()`, or `moveto()`. It might help to try to locate the features you want to interact with, using `locateOnSreen()` instead of using hard coded locations. It will be easier to determine where your script goes off the rails.

Comment: I am not using my mouse while this script is running, i tried everything, but once the mouse is clicked one of the icons, it becomes inmovable without me, moving my mouse.